# Is it possible to check if a webpage exists or no in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

`Is it` possible to check if a webpage exists or no. I have no idea how to do this

Answer (score -1):

Check if it can be downloaded to a string:-

```
Public Function MyFunc(URL As String) As String
    Dim sourceString As String = String.Empty
    Try
        sourceString = New Net.WebClient().DownloadString(URL)
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
    Return sourceString
End Function
'================================================
msgbox(MyFunc("http://etc ...")
```

Comment: A side note, the above will not compile. Also `WebClient` implements `IDisposable` so you should be wrapping the `WebClient` in a `Using` statement to release resources used by it.